# Truncate entries from a string column of pandas dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So, I have a list:

```
lst = [2, 4, 6, 245]
```

and I have a pandas Dataframe

```
 a                       b
 1                       2, 4, 10
 2                       245, 100
```

I want to remove entries from `b` which are not there in `lst`

So, expected output:

```
 a                       b
 1                       2, 4
 2                       245
```

How to do this?

EDIT (added null row in `b`):

```
 a                       b
 1                       2, 4, 10
 2                       245, 100
 3                      np.NaN
```

Expected output

```
      a                       b
      1                       2, 4
      2                       245
      3                      np.NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets try `explode`

```
s = df['b'].str.split(',').explode().astype(int)

df['b'] = s[s.isin(lst)].astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(", ".join)
```

---

```
print(df)

   a     b
0  1  2, 4
1  2   245
```

## Pre 0.25 Pandas Solution using `stack`

```
s = df['b'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().astype(int)
df['b'] = s[s.isin(lst)].astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(", ".join)
```

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @SumitSidana you probably don't have pandas 0.25 + see 2nd solution

Comment: yes, I made an edit to my question that `b` column may contain `np.NaN` as well. Your solution seems to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through column b and lst, using [itertool's product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get your result :

```
from itertools import product
df['b_new'] = [", ".join(entry for entry in first if entry in last)
               for first, last 
               in product(df.b.str.split(', '),[[str(entry) for entry in lst]])
              ]




df


    a       b      b_new
0   1   2, 4, 10    2, 4
1   2   245, 100    245
```

For the added data, with null, the code below should help :

```
df['b_new'] = [", ".join(entry for entry in first if entry in last) 
               #this uses the fact that nan != nan
               if first==first else np.nan 
               for first, last
               in product(df.b.str.split(', '),[[str(entry) for entry in lst]])
              ]


     a         b        b_new
0   1.0     2, 4, 10    2, 4
1   2.0     245, 100    245
2   3.0     NaN         NaN
```

Comment: your solution works fails for me because I just realized that b may have nulls. `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: ok. edit your code to include nulls; we will play with it and see how to improve on the result

Comment: I made the edit. It is unfortunate that I can accept only one answer (upvoted). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over all values in b and replace the array with one that does contains the whitelisted values.

```
cell = [val for val in cell if val in whitelist]
```